# Image not showing on page load when a max-height is being assigned via jQuery

Tags: jquery, load, window, slideshow, css

I have an issue.

I'm using jQuery to assign a max-hight to an image. The max height value is generated by getting the height of the slideshow the logo image is next to. Please take a look at the site: http://debourg-dev.ch/lestroisverres/

The affected code is:

```
var sliderHeight = $('.flexslider').height();
$('#logo img').css({'max-height': sliderHeight});

$(window).resize(function() {

    var sliderHeight = $('.flexslider').height();
    $('#logo img').css({'max-height': sliderHeight});

});
```

Once you start resizing the window the logo appears and scales fine as it should, so the issue looks like the script is loading before the slideshow height is determined. I've tried wrapping the affected code in a $(window).load function but it makes no difference.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is that this is running before any of the images in the slider are loaded. Since there's nothing in the slider yet `$('.flexslider').height` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
    controlNav: false,
    slideshowSpeed: 6000,
    animationDuration: 1600,
    start: function(slider) {
        var sliderHeight = this.height();
        $('#logo img').css({'max-height': sliderHeight});
    }
});
```

The `start` option runs the function when the slider displays its first image, so the image should be loaded by then, and the height will be known.

Comment: using the above, no max-height is applied to the logo image, so it the logo image is loaded on page load, but is not the correct size (unless you start resizing the screen). Anything else we can try? Thanks again

Comment: How is it supposed to know the correct size before the slider starts showing images, since the size is dependent on the images in the slider?

Comment: I don't know, does anyone else have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should use **height** instead **max-height**, because **max-height** determines just the maximum height. which in this case will always be the image size, and with this you can only scale it down.

//edit
so the problem with height 0 is described by Barmar, at point you setting height for the logo, javascript doesn't know yet what is the height, because it simply didn't load images yet.

as documentation shows, you have several callbacks:

```
start: function(){},            //Callback: function(slider) - Fires when the slider loads the first slide
added: function(){},            //{NEW} Callback: function(slider) - Fires after a slide is added
```

so you need to add the initial height setting into one of these instead in the document load callback.

Comment: His problem is that it's being set to 0. Setting `height` to 0 would have the same problem.

Comment: @Barmar yes I'm pretty certain you're right, and yes, I've tried using just height and it had the same problem. Any ideas on how I can run it after the images in the slider are loaded? Thanks

Comment: but still max-height will simply not scale logo to the height higher than an image height

Comment: He doesn't want to stretch the logo to match the slider, just keep it from going outside. That's what max-height is for.